# Execute multiple queries without losing the returning id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to execute this query multiple times

```
UPDATE product_variation
SET stock = (SELECT stock FROM product_variation WHERE id=14) - 1
WHERE id = 14 AND stock >= 1
RETURNING id
```

But the problem is i lose the values. I tried the union but it doesn't work. Is there any way?

Basically i have to update the stock number when user buy it and if the number is higher than 0
I need the returning id because i have to tell the user which stock is finished and he can't buy it
So the id (14) changes in every query and also the 1 can change

Comment: It looks like you're only sharing with us part of your code. Why would you need the UPDATE statement to return `id` if you already know the `id` value?

Comment: Because i need to know if the field is updated. If the statement doesn t update the field it returns empty

Comment: After every UPDATE statement that you run you can check how many rows were changed by that statement. It's generally called `ROWCOUNT` but the name of this parameter depends on your platform. From which language are you calling this UPDATE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a select to get the old value. To update multiple rows, use a WHERE clause that selects all the rows you want to update and use a CASE expression to subtract the value

```
UPDATE product_variation
  SET stock = case 
                when id = 14 then stock - 1
                when id = 15 then stock - 4
              end 
WHERE (id = 14 AND stock >= 1)
   or (id = 15 and stock >= 4)
RETURNING id, stock;
```

Alternatively you could provide a list of ids and min levels:

```
update product_variation pv
  set stock = stock - t.delta
from (
   values (14, 1), (15, 4), (16, 7)
) as t(id, delta)
where pv.id = t.id
  and pv.stock >= t.delta;
```